# size of saved docker images for base versus derived

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers

In an empty directory, I have run a sequence of commands shown in the following terminal capture:

```
$ echo -e "from alpine" > Dockerfile
$ docker build --tag alpine .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : from alpine
 ---> c059bfaa849c
Successfully built c059bfaa849c
Successfully tagged alpine:latest
$ docker image save -o alpine.tar alpine
$ echo -e "from alpine \nrun apk add --no-cache tini" > Dockerfile
$ docker build --tag tini .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.76MB
Step 1/2 : from alpine
 ---> c059bfaa849c
Step 2/2 : run apk add --no-cache tini
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e50ce83132ec
Successfully built e50ce83132ec
Successfully tagged tini:latest
$ docker image save -o tini.tar tini
$ ls -sh *.tar
 12M alpine.tar  5.7M tini.tar
```

As expected, the image labeled `tini` builds a further layer above the one shared with `alpine`. However, the resulting saved file for the former image is smaller than that for the latter.

Expected is that the image saved in the former file is a superset of the latter, and therefore larger.

Why is this expectation not confirmed by  observation?

Comment: It's probably because you previously tagged a different build with `alpine` and that image is occupying the `latest` tag.  I don't think you're saving the image you think you are.  If you run `docker image ls` I suspect you'll see an `alpine:<none>` image sitting at 5.64M and an `alpine:latest` around 12M.  Try using a different tag for your first image.  Brings up some other questions about the `<none>` tag...

Comment: The listing showed an Alpine image tagged  3.13.4. It showed as roughly the same size as `latest`, but after removing it, the size of new saved images dropped down to about the same size as the derived image.

Comment: However, both versions of `Dockerfile` had the same first line, and when built, the output showed the same tag for the base image, and the same hash identifier for the base layer (see original question).

Comment: Indeed, the issue is not with the build -- it's understanding what image is being tagged as what, and what image/tag is being saved.  As usual, the latest tag causes more problems than it solves.  If you figure it out I'm interested to know what's going on, I didn't find much detail on this.

Comment: Then the algorithms are different for image resolution from a  build file versus the `save` subcommand. I suppose the observation points to a flaw in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is something else was tagged `alpine` on your host when you did the build, and between the two commands, something pulled the correct alpine image down. But rather than guessing, you have the file to tell you exactly what was in that first alpine image. Extract the tar, review the manifest, and review the config the manifest points to. Here's an example with whatever old version of `alpine:latest` I happened to have on my machine:

```
$ cat manifest.json | jq .
[
  {
    "Config": "45683da4f97c23d92b878d2ad15eb66e94c9cab368e54797bcd4a4b20c915815.json",
    "RepoTags": [
      "test-alpine:latest"
    ],
    "Layers": [
      "4833c0e9afedb6022373ef7da2cee392c97a5f4438e7f52a1f940903db618437/layer.tar"
    ]
  }
]

$ cat 45683da4f97c23d92b878d2ad15eb66e94c9cab368e54797bcd4a4b20c915815.json | jq .
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ],
    "OnBuild": null
  },
  "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.553092363Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:aad4290d27580cc1a094ffaf98c3ca2fc5d699fe695dfb8e6e9fac20f1129450 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:e2eb06d8af8218cfec8210147357a68b7e13f7c485b991c288c2d01dc228bb68"
    ]
  }
}
```

When you compare the two images, if they were built from the same alpine base, they will have the same initial set of layers. In your case, they almost certainly won't.

Comment: Nothing happened between any two commands shown in the terminal capture, except any operations also shown in the capture. The capture represents a self-contained, reproducible demonstration.

Comment: @epl that's why I'm describing it as a guess because I can't reproduce it. But the answer here describes how you can debug what's actually happening using the files you have.